# C# anonymus delegates efficiency/safety

Tags: c#, delegates, performance, anonymous-delegates

I have progress form which delegate:

```
    // in ProgressForm thread
    public delegate void executeMethod(object parameters);      
    private executeMethod method;
    public object parameters;
    // ...
    private void ProgressForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         method.Invoke(parameters);
    }
```

Which way is better (mor efficient or safe) to apply - anonymus delegates call like this:

```
// in other thread
ProgressForm progress = new ProgressForm();
progress.ExecuteMethod = delegate
{
   // to do
}
```

or using separate method like this:

```
// in other thread
private void myMethod(object par)
{
     // to do
}

progress.ExecuteMethod = this.myMethod;
```

Comment: Your examples are different. In the first case, you have no `par` parameter.  Personally, I prefer the second, but any way is OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately they are surprisingly similar; simply, the compiler creates the hidden method internally for the anonymous case. There is no specific performance difference, although there are cases when it might choose to create a static method (if it doesn't use `this` or any captured variables) - that may help *marginally* (but not enough to get excited about)

I would use an anonymous method when:

- it is short and is logically related to the code that *inits* the anonymous method
- it perhaps uses additional context (captured variables) that are tricky to pass into `myMethod`

The main thing to watch is the notorious `foreach` (typically) captured variable gotcha, but in some cases it is also possible to bleed a reference into the anonymous method, extending the life-time of a *big* object unexpectedly.

For longer work, I would use the `myMethod` apprach.

Answer (score 2):

The performance is identical.  An anonymous delegate is converted by the compiler into a regular method like any other.  If you ILDSM the code you'll see that a real (but hidden) name is generated for the anonymous method.